# Finding the complex SDP matrix maximizing an eigenvalue-dependent criterion

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spheres, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

Let $v_1,\cdots,v_k \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $||v_i||=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ be a certain discretization of the n-sphere of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

In some optimization problem, I have to work with a complex semi-definite matrix variable $W$ of size $n$ for which I want to approximate linearly (by relying essentially on the trace operator) the maximum eigenvalue, noted $\lambda_{W,\text{max}}$ .

Since $\lambda_{W,\text{max}}=\max_{v\in\mathbb{C}^n\text{ s.t. }||v||=1} \ \ \ v^HWv$ (not linear in $W$), my idea (which may be not that new, although I have not find any article going in that direction so far) is to approximate this maximum eigenvalue of $W$ by

$\max_{1\leq i \leq k} \ \ \ v_i^HWv_i$

which I believe could be expressed linearly in semi-definite programming for instance.

My question is the following : since the $v_i$ are known, is there a way (either analytically or algorithmically) to find, before performing the optimization I am actually interested in, the complex SDP matrix $W$ that maximizes

$\dfrac{\lambda_{W,\text{max}}}{\max_{1\leq i \leq k} v_i^HWv_i}$

along with the value of that maximum ratio ?

Note 1 : in my particular case, it could be sufficient to determine that maximum ratio by considering only rank one $W$ matrices: I'm not sure it would simplify the analysis, but if it does, let's exploit that.

Note 2 : this ratio would be a way to know in advance by how much the n-sphere discretization can miss the actual value of the maximum eigenvalue (therefore the approximation used would be quantified which can be very valuable in my application)

Answer (score 1):

For any matrix SDP matrix $W$ of rank 1 there exists a unitary matrix $U$ and a positive $\lambda$ such that $W = U^*diag(\lambda,0,...)U$, and conversely. Hence the ratio you want to maximise can be maximised for $U$ unitary and $\lambda$ positive. Now for any $U$ and $\lambda$ we have
$$
v_i^*U^*diag(\lambda,0,...)Uv_i=\lambda |(Uv_i)_1|^2
$$
so your maximal ratio is
$$
\max_{U^*U = Id, \lambda >0}\frac{\lambda}{\max_{1\leq i \leq k}\lambda |(Uv_i)_1|^2} = \left( \min_{U^*U=Id} \max_{1\leq i \leq k} |(Uv_i)_1|\right)^{-2}.
$$
Also for any unity vector $u$, its image by the application $U \mapsto Uu$ is the unity sphere so you are left with
$$
\left( \min_{u \in \mathbb{S}} \max_{1\leq i \leq k} |\langle u,v_i\rangle|\right)^{-2}. 
$$

Comment: Waw thank you ! I think the way you formulated the problem allows to have a geometrical approach to it : we're looking for the direction in a n-dimensional space with the worst best approximation by the $v_i$ directions. I think it can be easily solved in 2D and 3D which inspires a conjecture for the general n-dimensional case I'm not sure how to prove. I'll post a dedicated question and link it here. Thanks again !

Comment: @Sycropane I got the same geometrical interpretation as you got, I cannot figure out an efficient algorithmic way to approach this minmax and nor can I figure out a theoretical way so I am very curious about your futur developments.

Comment: Also notice that 1) swapping min and max leads to $+ \infty$ 2) the minmax is null as soon as there exists a unity vector that is orthogonal to the $v_i$'s 3) the last formula does not involve $\lambda$ so to construct $W$ you only have to find $u$, build an orthonormal basis $(u,e_2,...,e_n)$ and let $U = [u|e_2|...|e_n]$ and $W = U^*diag(1,0,...)U$.

Comment: Thank you :) I agree with everything you commented. I'll definitely keep you posted on what I manage to find, if I find anything, fingers crossed.